# Setting Big Integer Number with non-zero terminated string

Tags: c++, c, gmp

There is a function to set a mpz number with a **zero-terminated string**.

```c
int mpz_set_str (mpz_t rop, const char *str, int base);
```

But there is no functions for a **non-zero terminated string**, and I would like to do that avoiding allocations and changes on the string.

```c
int mpz_set_strn (mpz_t rop, const char *str, size_t n, int base);
```

I found a similar discussion about this on [gmp-discuss](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2018-November/006288.html)

In my case, I would like to use part of the string. I've tried to simulate what the **mpz_set_str** function does in the background, but it seems it didn't work.

```cpp
#include <gmp.h>

int main(){

  const char * str_base16 = "354a546fde";

  mpz_t bn;
  mp_size_t xsize;
  mpz_init(bn);

  // setting bn with part of str_base16
  mpz_realloc2(bn, 8*4);
  xsize = mpn_set_str(bn->_mp_d, (unsigned char *)str_base16, 8, 16);
  bn->_mp_size = xsize;

  gmp_printf("%ZX\n", bn);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

`337637766`

Comment: If it's not null-terminated, then it can't be used by any function expecting a null-terminated string. It's simply not a *string* in the sense that C expects it to be. If you know that you need a null-terminated string, make sure you create space for the null-.terminator (and possibly add it, if it's not automatically added) from the very beginning, when the string is actually created or fetched.

Comment: An intermediate workaround is to recognize that you do not need to allocate a new string every time you call `mpz_set_str`. You only need some piece of thread-local data that's either pre-sized as large enough or can dynamically grow as required, and you copy your substring into that. It becomes the working buffer for any calls to this function, and you can build a wrapper around this. Most of the time, no allocations will take place, only copies which are pretty fast. Of course, this is only required if you cannot (even temporarily) modify the input (yours is a string literal).

Comment: As ever, beware premature optimisation, parsing the string is probably the costly bit.  Copying part of a string is easier in C++ than in C, why did you tag both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `mpz_set_str()`, it looks like you can use the low-level function `mpn_set_str()` directly, which takes a pointer and length to digits which start at 0 (not the ASCII character `'0'`).

```c
#include <math.h>
#include "gmp.h"

// Convert the string of decimal digits dig[0..n-1], each in the range 0..9, to
// the integer z. (n >= 1)
void dtoz(mpz_t z, unsigned char const *dig, mp_size_t n) {
    while (n > 1 && *dig == 0)
        dig++, n--;
    mp_size_t s = (M_LN10 / M_LN2 / (8 * sizeof(mp_limb_t))) * n + 2;
    _mpz_realloc(z, s);
    z->_mp_size = mpn_set_str(z->_mp_d, dig, n, 10);
}

int main(void) {
    mpz_t z;
    mpz_init(z);
    unsigned char dig[] = {
        3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4,
        3, 3, 8, 3, 2, 7, 9, 5, 0, 2, 8, 8, 4, 1, 9, 7, 1, 6, 9, 3, 9, 9, 3, 7,
        5, 1, 0, 5, 8};
    dtoz(z, dig, sizeof(dig));
    gmp_printf("%Zd\n", z);
    dtoz(z, dig + 12, 12);
    gmp_printf("%Zd\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```